# How to exclude Id when save the data in Nodejs using sequelize mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to save the user information. But I'm getting below error.

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
>   My Code is

```
var userObj = {userid: "aa", "emailid": "aa@aa.com", "user_type": "ENG"};
User.user
    .build(userObj)
    .save()
    .then(anotherTask => {
        console.log(anotherTask);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        throw error;
    });
```

I don't have id column in my table. How to exclude the id.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried quoting ```"userid":```?

Comment: Yes. I tried.  But same error I'm getting. The query is formed like "INSERT INTO `user` (`id`,`userid`,`emailid`,`user_type`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'aa','aa@aa.com','ENG');"

Comment: Does your table have a unique id column? If not, it should, and the library will expect the table to have one, apparently named 'id'.

Comment: Please add your `user` model

Comment: You might have deleted `id` column from the table and trying to insert `data`

Comment: Great @SloanThrasher. userid is unique. So I have created one fake id using userid. Now it is working. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you mentioned **How to exclude the id.**

You can also remove the `id` field completely by making the other field `primaryKey: true`,

```
sequelize.define('user', {
userid: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
},
emailid: Sequelize.STRING,
user_type: Sequelize.STRING
},{freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'user', id: false});
```

So, I added `primaryKey: true` to `userid` and now check, the `id` will get disappered from the table.

Comment: @Dharmarajan, also check this answer, This might be helpful to you.

Comment: No mentions. You can upvote and accept my answer, if you find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

IF there is no Id in table make unique column as Id filed.

```
sequelize.define('user', {
'id': {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'userid',
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
},
userid: Sequelize.STRING,
emailid: Sequelize.STRING,
user_type: Sequelize.STRING
```

},{freezeTableName: true, tableName: 'user', id: false});

```
{id: "aa", "userid": "aa", "emailid": "aa@aa.com", "user_type": "ENG"};
```